# Unit testing .net project by Asserting Status Code returning

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit.net

I am new to unit testing and `xunit`. I am writing unit tests that assert status codes returning. Is this something in the scope of Integration test or is it meeting unit testing logic?

For example I am asserting a get function's response like this:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task MyTest()
{
    SearchParam searchParam = new SearchParam() { };
    var bool= false;
    var bool2 = false;
    var actionResult = await _controller.Myfunction(searchParam, bool, bool2).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var okResult = actionResult.Result as OkObjectResult;
    Assert.True(okResult.StatusCode == 200, "Ok");
}
```

Comment: An assertion alone doesn't mean much for the difference between an integration and a unit test. Are you mocking all dependencies for your controller and making sure it follows the the correct logically flow given a particular input to get a 200? Then it's probably a unit test. Is the controller action executing through all of your controller's service dependencies? Then it's probably an integration test.

Comment: Can you share the code which you want to unit test and also the test code? It's not possible to suggest anything with the limited amount of information.

Comment: I shared the test method's code. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that status code was generated by accessing secondary infrastructure (making a web request or similar) then it should be an integration test.
This is because that secondary infrastructure might not always be up and running which may results in failing tests.

Unit tests should not be depending on such things.
A unit test must always be reproducible no matter what and must not dependend on outside resources.

**Update:**

Both unit tests and integration tests can usually be done using the same logic of your unit testing platform.
However you have to take into account that a test that qualifies as an integration test (see above) may fail due to external reasons.
This means that you have to treat the results of either test differently.

I would strongly suggest to put your integration tests into a separate test assembly that is not executed if you are running a build pipeline on commit.

If your integration tests fail because of external factors in a gated check-in environment, it will prevent any developer from committing changes to the branch until the secondary infrastructure is fixed to comply with your tests.
This is a situation you'd want to avoid at any cost since it can force developers into inactivity until i.e. network problems with another server in your building are resolved.

Comment: Yes, status code is generated by another service which makes these tests integration test in this context. But how can I use unittest logic for methods like these?

Comment: you can write a test that makes the request just like any other *act* section in a unit test and then *assert* on the status code received from the request. Just like you already do it.

Comment: thank you for clarification on the differences between unit and integration tests